# Create loop to write multiple files in C++?

Tags: c++, printf, fstream, ifstream

Let's say I have a program that does the follow:

```
for (i=1; i<10; i++)
{
   computeB(i);
}
```

where the `computeB` just outputs a list of values

```
computeB(int i)
{
  char[6] out_fname="output";
  //lines that compute `var` using say, Monte Carlo
  string fname = out_fname + (string)".values";
  ofstream fout(fname.c_str());
  PrintValue(fout,"Total Values", var);

}
```

From another file:

```
template <class T>
void PrintValue(ofstream & fout, string s, T v) {
  fout << s;
  for(int i=0; i<48-s.size(); i++) {
    fout << '.';
  }
  fout << " " << v << endl;
}
```

Before implementing that loop, `computeB` just outputted one file of values. I now want it to create multiple values. So if it originally created a file called "output.values", how can I write a loop so that it creates "output1.values", "output2.values", ..., "output9.values"?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the original code used the `PrintValue` function to output the values. I originally tried to save space and exclude this, but I just caused confusion

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding all the syntax errors in your code ...

1. Use the input value `i` to compute the output file name.
2. Use the file name to construct an `ofstream`.
3. Use the `ofstream` to write `var` to.

Here's what the function will look like:

```
void combuteB(int i)
{
   char filename[100];
   sprintf(filename, "output%d.values", i);
   ofstream fout(filename);
   fout << "total values";
   fout << " " << var << endl;  // Not sure where you get 
                                // var from. But then, your
                                // posted code is not
                                // exactly clean.
}
```

Comment: @user4352158, it's hard to tell where things could have gone wrong without seeing the actual code you use to compile. Try to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert from an `int` to a `string`:

```
void computeB(int i)
{
  if (std::ofstream fout("output" + std::to_string(i) + ".values"))
      fout << "total values" << " " << var << '\n';
  else
      throw std::runtime_error("unable to create output file");
}
```

Comment: When I try that , I get the error `to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’`. I am compiling with gcc/4.6 and I use a makefile
`

Comment: @user4352158: follow the link I provided to see which header you need to include.  Tip: google "std::XYZ site:cppreference.com" for such errors....

Comment: I'm supposed to use `#include <string>`, right? Even if I include that I  get the same error

Comment: @user4352158 sounds like your compiler either doesn't have support for C++11 features enabled, or lacks such support altogether.  If you're using any vaguely recent GNU `g++` just add `-std=c++11` to your compile line.  If you're on a pre Visual Studio version before 2013, upgrade.  For other compilers, check your docs.  Alternatively, for older compilers just `#include <sstream>`, then use `std;;ostringstream oss; oss << "output" << i << ".values"; if (std::ofstream fout(oss.str().c_str())) ... rest unchanged ...;`.